# How to register users to Amazon Cognito identity user pool by using Java

Tags: java, amazon-cognito

How to register users to `Amazon Cognito` identity  user pool by using `Java`. After following this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html) , I have done it by using `javascipt`, But I didn't find any way in `Java`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register users in Cognito User Pools by using AWS Java SDK. If you want to send them a welcome message and set a temporary password use the [AdminCreateUser](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminCreateUser.html) API. Otherwise you can use [SignUp](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_SignUp.html) API.

Signup is generally meant to be used from client side (frontend, native apps etc) and AdminCreateUser from your backend. Let us know your use case and we will be happy to help with any questions you have.

Best,
Rachit